# ActionScript se tornou inútil?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Com o advento do HTML5 e CSS3, é correto afirmar que a linguagem [ActionScript](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) usada em aplicações [Flash](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) se tornou uma linguagem "morta" ou ela foi aproveitada em alguma outra aplicação da Adobe?

Comment: _Downvoters_ podem deixar um comentário. Seu voto negativo se torna bastante útil quando tem uma justificativa, é garantido o direito de opinião.

Comment: Eu não digo 100% morta ,porque tem empresas que ainda usa essa tecnologia para determinado fins ,um deles é fazer curso dinâmico porem essa tecnologia já esta sendo substituída pelo famoso javascript,html e css,foque seus esforço nessas outras tecnologias só algumas empresas que ainda usa mas logo logo até elas vão migrar aos poucos.

Comment: Veja https://www.quora.com/Is-ActionScript-dead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trabalho com a tecnologia há alguns anos, desde de seu ápice. Posso dizer que eu vivi os altos e baixos do [actionscript-3](/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) e fiquei triste em saber que [em 2020 a Adobe vai encerrar definitivamente o suporte ao Flash Player](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/), um dos mais bem sucedidos plugins da era 2000.

**Introdução ao Adobe AIR**

Respondendo sua pergunta, parece que o ActionScript ainda está longe de morrer. Atualmente [existem milhares de aplicativos desenvolvidos](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/gaming.html) com a linguagem na Apple Store e Google Play. O que realmente aconteceu foi que a Adobe desistiu de manter as aplicações para web e concluiu que [irá focar para o mercado de desenvolvimento mobile](http://g1.globo.com/tecnologia/noticia/2011/11/adobe-vai-parar-de-desenvolver-flash-para-navegadores-de-celular-diz-site.html). Isso se deu ao fato de que havia um declínio do Flash Player na plataforma móvel e que comprometia a experiência de usuário, visto que em smartphones da época o Flash ainda era um programa pesado, mesmo com o lançamento do [Flash Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Lite) (além também do [empurrãozinho do Steve Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoughts_on_Flash)), o que não mudou muito desde o lançamento do iPhone, apesar dos esforços da Adobe.

A máquina virtual que está *substituíndo* o Flash Player atualmente é o [Adobe AIR](https://www.adobe.com/pt/products/air.html) (incrível algumas pessoas ainda não saberem que ele existe e geralmente o conhecem como "o programinha chato que precisa instalar pra tal joguinho"). Ele é capaz de compilar para multiplataformas desktop, mobile e também algumas TVs e hoje é minha principal ferramenta de trabalho.

Vale lembrar também que a linguagem ActionScript é aproveitada em praticamente todos os softwares de codificação da Adobe, afinal é a dona da tecnologia. Porém, com a popularização da linguagem e os SDKs disponibilizados gratuitamente, surgiram outros programas gratuitos, como o [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org).

Você ainda consegue utilizar [ANEs](https://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html) que são Extensões Nativas da Adobe. Elas permitem que você "extenda" a linguagem ActionScript, fazendo ela se comunicar com linguagens nativas do dispositivo em que a aplicação está sendo desenvolvida, como Java em Android, Swift em iOS, C# em Windows, etc...

**Onde se usa atualmente o ActionScript**

Com o Adobe AIR, posso afirmar <strike>com propriedade</strike> que são desenvolvidos programas **internos** como Servidores Socket (para jogos online, por exemplo), programas de comunicação com Banco de Dados Mysql e SQLite, auxiliadores em servidores RTMP, programa de conversão de mídia e existem também alguns programas externos para exibição de mídia como vídeos, músicas e, claro, swf (que é o ponto forte do AS3).

Ao contrário do que muitos pensam, ainda se utiliza o Flash Player para certas coisas. Porém, como eu citei, mais raramente você começa a vê-lo na web. Algumas atividades em que ele se encaixa é em Digital Signage, por exemplo, que é utilizado para exibição de informações em tempo real e nisso o Flash ainda é bom. Você ainda pode ver alguns softwares (raros) na web muito bons, como [Pixlr Editor](https://pixlr.com/editor/), que com certeza vai sair do ar daqui um pouco.

**Segurança, infelizmente...**

O que ainda torna inviável a utilização do ActionScript para programas grandes, fechados e seguros é algo que Adobe vem combatendo até hoje. Não muito diferente de outras linguagens o as3 ainda possui muitas falhas de seguranças e muitos bugs são corrigidos a cada versão que se lança, porém devido a sua popularidade, a linguagem se tornou o principal alvo de invasores e *crackers* invadirem o computador dos usuários, seja por meio de simples avisos de "Flash Player desatualizado" até falhas no *core* da VM.

Um programa que vem tornando a vida dos programadores <strike>um inferno</strike> ruim é o [JPEXS](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/download/), que abre qualquer tipo de arquivo swf, inclusive aqueles ofuscados, e torna todo o código do seu programa disponível em instantes. Isso significa que o desenvolvimento de qualquer coisa em as3 é comparado a uma aplicação web (talvez até menos seguro), o que o torna menos vantajoso, visto que na web toda aplicação está apta a funcionar em qualquer plataforma.

**Conclusão**

Hoje em dia o mercado de programação está bastante competitivo e essa competitividade está se encerrando para a linguagem as3. Muita ajuda que procuro da comunidade ativa de programadores é no SOen e nem lá você acha resultados. Há algumas coisas impossíveis de se realizar no AS3, seja por limitações da linguagem ou do projeto. Arriscar algo com o ActionScript depois de 2020 (ou até depois de hoje) é <strike>na minha opinião</strike> dar um tiro no escuro.

Answer (score 3):

ActionScript não é uma linguagem usada apenas no Flash.

Você pode usar no lado do servidor com o RedTamarin por exemplo. Você pode usar no FlexJS. Você pode usar no Flex. E obviamente no próprio Flash. E ainda pode criar projetos web e desktop com Flash e AIR.

Projeto RedTamarin: http://redtamarin.com/about/description

Exemplo de AS3 (achou que lembre alguma coisa?). O legal é que o AS3 era orientado ao objeto. Você podia *instanciar* algum elemento e trata-lo com AS3. Também tinha a possibilidade de importar dados *XML* para popular elementos dentro do Flash.

```
botao.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, escreve)
function escreve(e:MouseEvent){
   texto.text = "Olá, mundo!"
}
```

Até pouco tempo vi uma aplicação em Flex rodando normalmente no Browser. Apesar disso, não sei se seria a melhor opção atualmente, mesmo tendo todo o background da *Adobe*, e na minha opinião AS3 ainda não morreu. O Flash talvez sim...

A Google mesmo tem uma ferramenta de animação bem interessante, ***Google Web Design*** que permite fazer animações responsivas, com o conceito de `"Time Line"` e `"Actions"` e no final te permite exportar em HTML5/CSS3 *(otimizado e mobile friendly)* - Ponto a menos para o Flash nesse quesito.

Link do Google Web Design https://www.google.com/webdesigner/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não morre tão cedo, a Adobe já adaptou o AS a isto.

No Animate (substituto do Flash) o AS3 é usado junto com JavaScript para dar saída no canvas do HTML5. Diferente do antigo Flash o Animante não está restrito somente à geração de arquivos SWF, a partir dos códigos AS3/JS ele exporta arquivos em HTML5 e JavaScript, vinculando inclusive à bibliotecas externas como CreateJS como você pode ver aqui: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html

Possibilitando a criação de games, objetos de aprendizagem interativos etc, tudo em HTML5 canvas. Uso muito estes recursos no trabalho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]